Bash: How to get value from named key in multi-dimensional array
I get a "bad substitution" error when trying to get a named key from a dynamically-referenced array.
GNU Bash version 4.1.2(2)
WORKS:
declare -rA DBONE=([system_name]='ABC' [dbname]='abc_database' [dbusername]='user1')
declare -rA DBTWO=([system_name]='DEF' [dbname]='def_database' [dbusername]='user2')
declare -rA DBTHREE=([system_name]='XYZ' [dbname]='xyz_database' [dbusername]='user3')

# works: get value when using the real name of the array, e.g. "DBTWO"
echo ${DBTWO["dbname"]}

Output: "def_database" (correct)
ERROR: bad substitution
declare -rA DBONE=([system_name]='ABC' [dbname]='abc_database' [dbusername]='user1')
declare -rA DBTWO=([system_name]='DEF' [dbname]='def_database' [dbusername]='user2')
declare -rA DBTHREE=([system_name]='XYZ' [dbname]='xyz_database' [dbusername]='user3')

# create an array of the arrays
declare -a databases=(DBONE DBTWO DBTHREE)

# get the first array (e.g. DBONE)
database="${databases[0]}"
echo "The dbname is ${$database[dbname]}"
echo "The dbname is ${$database}[dbname]"

Output:
./myscript.sh: ${$database[dbname]}: bad substitution
./myscript.sh: ${$database}[dbname]: bad substitution

Ultimately, my final goal is to loop over the array of arrays, like this:
# create an array of the arrays
declare -a databases=(DBONE DBTWO DBTHREE)
for ((i=0; i<"${#databases[*]}"; i++)); do
    database="${databases[$i]}"
    dbname="${database[dbname]}"
    echo "The database is $database, and the dbname is $dbname"
done    

Note: my version of bash (GNU Bash version 4.1.2(2)) does not support declare "-n".  It allows these options:
declare: usage: declare [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

databases is not an array of arrays; it's just an array of array names.

Any reason not to install a newer version of bash?

Chepner, Thank you for the clarification.
Ed Morton, I'm using the version provided by my shared hosting provider (Godaddy).

You can use indirect reference :
declare -rA DBONE=([system_name]='ABC' [dbname]='abc_database' [dbusername]='user1')
declare -rA DBTWO=([system_name]='DEF' [dbname]='def_database' [dbusername]='user2')
declare -rA DBTHREE=([system_name]='XYZ' [dbname]='xyz_database' [dbusername]='user3')

declare -a databases=(DBONE DBTWO DBTHREE)
for ((i=0; i<"${#databases[*]}"; i++)); do
    database="${databases[$i]}"
    ref="$database[dbname]"
    dbname="${!ref}"
    echo "The database is $database, and the dbname is $dbname"
done


Interesting to note that $ref is just the string DBONE[dbname] with the embedded square brackets, NOT a lookup of its own of ANY sort, but when used as a reference key it works fine. You could have set it as literally ref="${databases[0]}[dbname]". It does require the extra step of storing that string first each time though. Still, this is nice!

@PaulHodges Indeed, I used $database because it's there already in OP.

Oh, I understood. Wasn't criticizing at all. Just clumsily trying to expand on it. :) I don't think I've used quite this particular application of a reference to an associative array element, and was "thinking out loud" so to speak, and thought someone else might benefit from the perspective. That's all.

Since the OP said their bash version didn't support name references, I had assumed it also didn't support indirect variables (IMHO it's almost impossible to google which bash version introduced any given feature) so, good to know indirect variables did exist first.

bash doesn't do multidimensional arrays, but associative arrays allow arbitrarily complex strings as keys, so if you refactor your design just a little it's effectively the same thing.
Just use a standard name for each field with a key appended to differentiate them.
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -rA db=( [system_name:DB1]='ABC' [dbname:DB1]='abc_database' [dbusername:DB1]='user1'
                 [system_name:DB2]='DEF' [dbname:DB2]='def_database' [dbusername:DB2]='user2'
                 [system_name:DB3]='XYZ' [dbname:DB3]='xyz_database' [dbusername:DB3]='user3' )

declare -ra databases=( DB1 DB2 DB3 )

setdata(){
  local dbkey="$1";
  declare -g dbname=${db["dbname:$dbkey"]}
  declare -g username=${db["dbusername:$dbkey"]}
  declare -g system_name=${db["system_name:$dbkey"]}
}

echo "With key variables -"
field=dbname; database="${databases[0]}"; key="$field:$database"
printf '\n%s\n' "The $field for $database is ${db[$key]}"

printf '\nRaw access -\n'
printf '\n%s\n' "The system_name for ${databases[1]} is ${db[system_name:${databases[1]}]}"

printf '\nLooping with function:\n\n'

for database in "${databases[@]}"
do setdata $database
   echo "$database: dbname=$dbname username=$username system_name=$system_name"
done
echo

In use:
$: ./tst
With key variables -

The dbname for DB1 is abc_database

Raw access -

The system_name for DB2 is DEF

Looping with function:

DB1: dbname=abc_database username=user1 system_name=ABC
DB2: dbname=def_database username=user2 system_name=DEF
DB3: dbname=xyz_database username=user3 system_name=XYZ


If you can use a newer bash version, it become super easy using namerefs:
for name in DB{ONE,TWO,THREE}; do
  declare -n ref="$name"
  printf 'array: %s; system: %s; db: %s\n' "$name" "${ref[system_name]}" "${ref[dbname]}"
done

array: DBONE; system: ABC; db: abc_database
array: DBTWO; system: DEF; db: def_database
array: DBTHREE; system: XYZ; db: xyz_database

I don't recall if namerefs were introduced in version 4.4 or 5.0
